# How does a row in subreport link to a a row in main report in the designer? (Crystal Reports)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports report in Visual Studio 2008 which has a subreport.
The source for each report is a separate datatable. Say main report datatable schema is
id1, id2, firstname. subreport has datatable schema: id1, id2, lastname. When the report displays, it displays firstname, lastname for each record.

If the reports are joined by id1, how do I change it so that it's joined by id2 instead in the report designer? I am not very familiar with CR and I can't find where the reports are joined and by which column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony,

You will need to right click the subreport, and choose Change Subreport Links.  This window will pull up a list of available fields and you choose the right arrow to create the link.

Please let me know if this doesn't do the trick.